# fpm-php + nginx + POST data

Tags: php, docker, nginx

When sending a POST request, fpm-php chaotically returns either a normally processed PHP script `<?=die("111");?>` will return either “111” or a response of 200 and the body of the POST request itself, in this form: “rnd=1173943626&sessid=b2e74736d05a7d16efbfa99a603c66ad”.

Nginx.conf without any specific things, PHP processing is performed in this form:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files       $uri @bitrix;
   fastcgi_pass     fpm-php:9000;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80385&edit=1, closed fpm-php 9000 port for access from the network.

Answer (score 0):

First of all move `include fastcgi_params` directive to the top, before any **fastcgi_param** directive, to make sure it won't override params, you define inside location.

It seems same request is processed by different scripts, check what @bitrix fallback does.

You can add access and error logs inside nginx configuration and after making request check that files. If it doesnt help, you can install **[nginx echo module](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module)**, it really helps to debug.

Which php version are you using? I have heard old version had same problem, under **PHP 5.3**